# Differences between two similar definitions

Tags: scheme

Is there any difference between

```
(define make-point cons)
```

and

```
(define (make-point x y)
  (cons x y))
```

?

Is one more efficient than the other, or are they totally equivalent?

Comment: They are not totally different.  If you later **(set! cons ...)**, then the first case keeps acting like the original **cons**, whereas the second reflects the new value of **cons**.  (It might not be allowed to change the value of **cons**, since it's built-in, but in general you can change the value of variables, including those whose values are functions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different issues here.

As [Oscar Lopez points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28884417/1281433), one is an indirection, and one is a wrapper.  [Christophe De Troyer did some timing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888604/1281433) and noted that without optimization, the indirection can take twice as much time as the indirection.  That's because the alias makes the *value* of the two variables be the *same* function.  When the system evaluates **(cons …)** and **(make-point …)** it evaluates the variables **cons** and **make-point** and gets the *same* function back.  In the indirection version, **make-point** and **cons** are *not* the same function.  **make-point** is a *new* function that makes another call to **cons**.  That's *two* function calls instead of one.  So speed *can* be an  issue, but a good optimizing compiler might be able to make the difference negligible.

However, there's a *very* important difference if you have the ability to *change* the value of either of these variables later.  When you evaluate **(define make-point kons)**, you evaluate the variable **kons** *once* and set the value of **make-point** to that *one* value that you get at that evaluation time.  When you evaluate **(define (make-point x y) (kons x y))**, you're setting the value of **make-point** to a new function.  Each time that function is called, the variable **kons** is evaluated, so any change to the variable **kons** is reflected.  Let's look at an example:

```
(define (kons x y)
  (cons x y))

(display (kons 1 2))
;=> (1 . 2)
```

Now, let's write an indirection and an alias:

```
(define (kons-indirection x y)
  (kons x y))

(define kons-alias kons)
```

These produce the same output now:

```
(display (kons-indirection 1 2))
;=> (1 . 2)

(display (kons-alias 1 2))
;=> (1 . 2)
```

Now let's redefine the **kons** function:

```
(set! kons (lambda (x y) (cons y x))) ; "backwards" cons
```

The function that was a *wrapper* around **kons**, that is, the indirection, sees the new value of **kons**, but the alias does not:

```
(display (kons-indirection 1 2)) 
;=> (2 . 1)  ; NEW value of kons

(display (kons-alias 1 2))
;=> (1 . 2)  ; OLD value of kons
```

Answer (score 2):

Semantically they're equivalent: `make-point` will `cons` two elements. But the first one is creating an *alias* of the `cons` function, whereas the second one is defining a new function that simply calls `cons`, hence it'll be slightly slower, but the extra overhead will be negligible, even inexistent if the compiler is good.

Comment: In many cases, a good compiler will optimize away the difference between the two.

Comment: @JohnClements If it's not allowed to set the value of `cons` afterward, then the aliasing can be optimized away, but if you can change the value of `cons`, then `(define make-point cons)` will have preserved the old value, whereas `(define (make-point x y) (cons x y))` will reflect the new value of `cons`.

Comment: I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28901299/1281433) with a bit more detail.

Comment: see my response above.

Answer (score 2):

For `cons`, there is no difference between your two versions.

For variadic procedures like `+`, the difference between `+` and `(lambda (x y) (+ x y))` is that the latter constrains the procedure to being called with two arguments only.

Comment: There *is* a difference, though slight, in these.  In `(define make-point cons)`, you're setting the value of the variable `make-point` to be the *same* function that is the value of the variable `cons`. In `(define (make-point x y) (cons x y))`, you're setting the value of make-point to a *new function* that happens to call the value of the variable `cons`.  That's two function invocations instead of one when you do `(make-point x y)`.  In addition to that, you'd have different behavior if the value of `cons` is changed later.

Comment: I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28901299/1281433) with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity I did a quick and dirty experiment. It seems to be the case that just aliasing `cons` is almost twice as fast than wrapping it in a new function.

```
(define mk-point cons)

(define (make-point x y)
  (cons x y))

(let ((start (current-inexact-milliseconds)))
(let loop ((n 100000000))
      (mk-point 10 10)
      (if (> n 0)
          (loop (- n 1))
          (- (current-inexact-milliseconds) start))))
(let ((start (current-inexact-milliseconds)))
(let loop ((n 100000000))
      (make-point 10 10)
      (if (> n 0)
          (loop (- n 1))
          (- (current-inexact-milliseconds) start))))


;;; Result    
4141.373046875
6241.93212890625
>
```

Ran in DrRacket 5.3.6 on Xubuntu.

Comment: Try running it in command-line `racket` instead of DrRacket. The optimisations used for that are more aggressive, IIRC. When I tested that in `racket` 5.3.4 in Debian, I got 2162.788818359375
and 1930.303955078125.

Comment: You are correct! The speedup is almost nothing. After a few runs with longer iterations I get average timings of 2943 ms for alias and 2546 for new function. So it is actually faster..

Comment: Does this optimization depend on immutability of variable bindings?  In Scheme (the question is tagged with [tag:scheme], after all), where one can set the value of the variable, would this optimization still be possible?

Comment: When you wrap your code as a module (e.g., by starting the file with #lang racket), Racket knows that the variable won't be mutated, and treats it as immutable (side note: this can bite you if you try to mutate it outside of the module). In Racket 6.1.1.8, the times I get are 235.29 milliseconds and 235.41 milliseconds. That is, the difference is about a tenth of a millisecond. TL;DR. Don't spend your life tuning your code for an optimizer.

Comment: P.S.: I think that Racket optimization may have improved substantially since 5.3.6.