# Is it more semantically correct to bind a lambda to a function or a var?

Tags: lambda, common-lisp

I'm writing a simple macro that binds a name to an expression that returns a lambda, but since common lisp has namespaces that are different for functions and values, I'd need to `funcall` it regardless of whether I wrap it in a `defun` or `defvar`.

```
(defun foo () (lambda-returning-expr)) 
(defvar bar (lambda-returning-expr)) 

(funcall (foo)) ; evaluates correctly 
(funcall bar) ; also evaluates
```

So which is the more correct way? Or rather, which is mostly preferred by lispers?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `(funcall (foo))` that's working?

Comment: you know what? I've done so many tests that I got it all mixed up, of course you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun foo () (lambda-returning-expr)) 
(defvar bar (lambda-returning-expr))
```

You need **funcall** for both cases, e.g.,  **(funcall (foo))** and **(funcall bar)**, but there's a *very* big difference in that **(foo)** involves an extra function call that evaluates **(lambda-returning-expr)** each time, so you can get a different function back each time.

- If you expect that there might be different functions, then using a function like **foo** would be appropriate.
- If you expect just one, then the variable, like **bar**, would be appropriate.
- If you expect the *user* to want to change the function (e.g., with **(let ((bar …)) ...)** as part of an API, then a variable definitely makes sense.  This is used in the standard, e.g., for [***macroexpand-hook***](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_mexp_h.htm).  If you need to do this, then the special variable is almost certainly the way to go, since Common Lisp doesn't have dynamically scoped functions.

There was actually a similar Scheme question recently, [Differences between two similar definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28884211/1281433), where some of these issues are discussed.

Answer (score 2):

`(funcall (foo))` is not a vise choice since you do two function calls instead of one. If you want to make a global function you can use this:

```lisp
(setf (symbol-function 'foo) (lambda (x) x))
(foo 10) ; ==> 10
```

You can use variables too, but remember that `defvar` only makes sure the varible is bound.

```lisp
(defvar *test* 10)
*test* ; ==> 10
(defvar *test* (lambda (x) x))
*test* ; ==> 10 (not changed since it's already existing)
```

If you want it always to be set to the evaluated expression use `defparameter` instead.

```lisp
(defparameter *test* 10)
*test* ; ==> 10
(defparameter *test* (lambda (x) x))
*test* ; ==> #<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (X) X>
```

BTW: `defvar` and `defparameter` makes special variables. Remember the `*earmuffs*` so you don't get stuck with strange bugs because of dynamic scope.